# Importing Java file as Jar from another selenium project giving me symbol not found exception

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jar

I have a selenium maven project in which I have lib containing 4 java files which I do not want expose to client so I have exported them to a Jar file through Eclipse jar wizard and share it with them.
I have imported the jar successfully with no errors and even on clicking over the class initiation it is redirecting me to the class files methods
But on executing the project it is giving me error Symbol not found "compilation error".

Please help me here as what needs to be done as there are no errors in the project

Comment: what did you mean by " which I do not want expose to client so I have exported and share it with them."?  If I'm understanding correctly, you'll want to ditch maven and download the jars that are necessary yourself.  Then add them individually to your project.

Comment: No , I am doing it that way i have same setup at client location also with all maven jars, Its basically 3 files which i have written code i do not want to share that with them directly just give add as a jar in the project and it should execute ... but that's not happening it giving me error as cannot find symbol.